# PrimeNg - P-Dropdown Not loading Options and styling, not working

Tags: angular7, dropdown, primeng

I have an `Angular` project with `PrimeNg` Library and I want to use `p-dropdown` component I imported it at `app.module` file like this:

```
import { DropdownModule } from "primeng/dropdown";

imports: [
    DropdownModule,

  ],
```

And when I use it on an `html` file:

```
 <div class="charts-dropdown">
    <p-dropdown [options]="chartsDropdownLookup" [(ngModel)]="selectedChartOption"></p-dropdown>
 </div>
```

This is How it looks:

[image]

It doesn't render my `[options]` array which is an array with `label` and `value` attributes and it doesn't show the styling properly.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you please show your **chartDropdownLookup** values, please refer this PrimeNG documentation (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown)

Comment: Hi, 

Heres is my lookup: 

chartsDropdownLookup = [{label: "Por Zona", value: "zona"}, {label: "Por tipo de cerveza", value: "dia"}, {label: "Historico", value: "historico"} ];

Comment: could you please print and see your  `chartsDropdownLookup` in your HTML file using this `{{chartsDropdownLookup | json}}` or in your console log. without see your **.ts** file very difficult to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same issue.

Ensure the "styles" array includes the prime ng style sheets under the "build" AND "test" (under "architect" under the project under "projects"):

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
],
```

Other stylesheets will probably already be there. Other themes are available.

I only found the relevant documentation after working out the solution, but it is detailed here on the PrimeNG web site:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup in the Styles Configuration section at the bottom of the page.